# Google custom search

Tags: api, search, google-custom-search

My application (Java based) is not hosted over internet or web .  I need to provide search functionality (Google Custom Search) , which helps user to search the contents through the webpages in my application .

Can I achieve this as my application is not hosted on the web?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use Google Custom Search to index private web pages. You can however use the [Search API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/search/) in Google App Engine to index and search private content (I'm assuming you are using App Engine Java based on the question and tags).

It does require a bit of coding on your part so it's not quite as easy as Google Custom Search but it should work for your use case.

Comment: Thanks Ian. From the Search Api it looks like data gets indexed .

Comment: From the Search Api it looks only data gets indexed . I need to provide a search box , where user provide some information (say any product information) . So, I need to display all the possible url's of the  webpages (like google search) within our  intranet application, which contains the information of that particular product .  I was just looking one alternative "google search appliance" , but it is too costly . Is there be any other alternative , which can provide google like search to search index and crawl the webpages and provide content base search.